# fetch data error with next.js 401 response code

Tags: vercel, next.js14

I am encountering a peculiar issue with fetching data in my Next.js application. When running the app locally, everything works fine; however, when deployed on Vercel, I consistently receive a 401 error code when attempting to hit the API endpoint.

Here are the relevant files in my project:

1. app/api/posts/route.js:

```
    // app/api/posts/route.js
    
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
    
    export async function GET() {
        return NextResponse.json({ items: [{id:1, title:"Hello World"}]})
    }
    
    export async function POST() {
        return NextResponse.json({ hello: "abc"})
    }
```

2. app/blog/page.js:

```
    // app/blog/page.js
    
    import getData from "@/app/lib/getData"
    
    export default async function BlogPage() {
      const data = await getData()
      const items = data && data.items ? [...data.items] : []
    
      console.log(data)
      console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV)
      console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL)
    
      return (
        <main>
          <h1>Blog</h1>
          
          <p>posts:</p>
          {items && items.map((item, idx)=>{
            return <li key={`post-${idx}`}>{item.title}</li>  
          })}
        </main>
      )
    }
```

3. app/lib/getDomain.js:

```
    // app/lib/getDomain.js
    
    export default function getDomain() {
        console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV)
        console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL)
        const protocol = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === "production" ? "https" : "http" 
        const domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL : "localhost:3000"
    
        return `${protocol}://${domain}`
    }
```

4. app/lib/getData.js:

```
    // app/lib/getData.js
    
    import getDomain from "@/app/lib/getDomain"
    
    export default async function getData() {
      const domain = getDomain()
      const endpoint = `${domain}/api/posts`
    
      console.log(endpoint)
    
      const res = await fetch(endpoint)
    
      console.log(res)
    
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
      }
    
      if (res.headers.get('content-type') !== 'application/json') {
        return {items:[]}
      }
    
      return res.json()
    }
```

I've included logs in the code to help trace the issue. Any insights into why I'm getting a 401 error code on Vercel but not locally would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here are the console logs:

```
production
my-vercel-123abc-projects.vercel.app
https://my-vercel-123abc-projects.vercel.app/api/posts
production
my-vercel-123abc-projects.vercel.app
https://my-vercel-123abc-projects.vercel.app/api/posts
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 401,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 1758.9642749999948,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 1758.9642749999948,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 0,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: [Array],
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined, length: undefined, source: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: [
      '_vercel_sso_nonce=KDscsdfgregvgVderlP3YmHxS; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax'
    ],
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(11) {
      'cache-control' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'set-cookie' => [Object],
      'strict-transport-security' => [Object],
      'x-frame-options' => [Object],
      'x-robots-tag' => [Object],
      'x-vercel-id' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Same here for me, did you find the solution to this issue ? I'm also using `VERCEL_URL`

Comment: Ok I think I know why we have this issue, basically we are trying to fetch data from an API endpoint that is not built yet, so instead of trying to fetch data from your API routes ,try to fetch data directly inside your React Server Components.

Basically, when you build your project (with Vercel or locally), your endpoints are not built yet (locally yes, because you are in dev and I think that it work differently)

Answer (score 3):

For my use case around this question, the error was being caused by the "Vercel Authentication" from Project Settings. Once I disabled it, the whole project worked.

Maybe you'll need to setup CORS if using `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL`

References:

Vercel Authentication: https://vercel.com/docs/security/deployment-protection/methods-to-protect-deployments/vercel-authentication

CORS: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-cors-next-js-handle-cross-origin-requests/

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `_vercel_jwt` cookie in the headers of your `fetch` call. You can find it in the request headers of the `request` you are trying to hit directly from the browser.

example:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Cookie: '_vercel_jwt='+<cookie value>,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an issue with how I was expecting the vercel's domains.
I was expecting something like:

```
https://my-vercel-123abc-projects.vercel.app/api/posts
```

but got something like this:

```
https://my-vercel-vanilla.vercel.app/api/posts
```

Or something a bit off.

This `getDomain` function did the trick manipulating the subdomains.

```
export default function getDomain() {
    const environment = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV;
    const isProduction = environment === "production";
    const isStaging = environment === "staging";
    const protocol = (isProduction || isStaging)  ? "https" : "http";

    const domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL : "localhost:3000"    

    if (!isProduction && domain === "localhost:3000") {
        return `${protocol}://${domain}`;
    }

    const urlObject = new URL(`${protocol}://${domain}`);
    const hostnameSplit = urlObject.hostname.split(".");
    const subdomain = hostnameSplit[0].split("-")[0];
    const secondLevelDomain = hostnameSplit[1];
    const topLevelDomain = hostnameSplit[2];

    const finalDomain = `${subdomain}.${secondLevelDomain}.${topLevelDomain}`;
    return `${protocol}://${finalDomain}`
}
```